# Get All Line Items Checkout Event

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I'm looking to fetch all line items and send it as a POST request to an endpoint. I've had a look through the class references but can't seem to find a way to get all the line items that are currently active.

```
Event::on(
  Payments::class,
  Payments::EVENT_BEFORE_CAPTURE_TRANSACTION,
  function(TransactionEvent $event) {

        $transaction = $event->transaction;
        // @var LineItem $lineItem
        $lineItem = $event->lineItem;

        $client = new \Guzzle\Http\Client([
            // You can set any number of default request options.
            'Authorization'  => 'qdaiciDiyMaTjxMt, 74026b3dc2c6db6a30a73e71cdb138b1e1b5eb7a97ced46689e2d28db1050875',
        ]);


        // Add Cart Data to an Array
        $order_data = array(
            'product_id' => $lineItem->id,
            'quantity' => $lineItem->quantity
        );
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is in this bit:

```php
        // @var LineItem $lineItem
        $lineItem = $event->lineItem;
```

Looking at the event in question:

https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/3.x/events.html#beforecapturetransaction

...this shows that you get a `Transaction` model supplied in this event:

https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/api/v3/craft-commerce-models-transaction.html#public-properties

...note that model gives you direct access to the related `order` element:

https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/api/v3/craft-commerce-elements-order.html

...from which you can then retrieve all the line items (and products etc associated with them), by looping over `order.lineItems`